# How to get rid of the syntax error in this code?

Tags: perl

Below I'v proided just a chunk of a huge perl script I am trying to write. I am getting syntax errors in else statement but in the console window its only saying syntax error at perl script and not clearly telling the error. I am trying to create a variable file `file_no_$i.txt` and copy contents of `t_code.txt` in it and then find and replace string in the variable file with some selected keys of hash `%defines_2`

```
open ( my $pointer, "<", "t_code.txt" ) or die $!;
my $out_pointer;    

 for (my $i=0 ; $i <=$#match  ; $i++) {
    for (my $j=0; $j <= $#match ; $j++) {          
       if ($match[$i]=~$match[$j]) {
              next;
            } 

     else {            
       my $file_name = "file_no_$i.txt";                                             
       open $out_pointer, ">" , $file_name  or die "Can't open the output file!";
       copy("$file_name","t_code.txt") or die "Copy failed: $!";
       my @lin = <$out_pointer>;
         foreach $_(@lin) {
      $_ =~ s/UART90_BASE_ADDRESS/$defines_2{ $_ = grep{/$match[$i]/} (keys %defines_2)};                              
                   }            
            }        
      }
}
```

Comment: try to comment the line beginning with $_ =~ ... , and if you don't have syntax errors , that's the line you have to fix

Comment: You are trying to read from your output file handle `$out_pointer`. You are also trying to put code into the replacement part of the substitution without using an eval modifier `/e`. Moreover, your `grep` statement is incorrect, you are assigning a new value to `$_` (which is discarded anyway) -- but more importantly, if you are only expecting one match, you can just do `$defines_2{$match[$i]}`.

Comment: Also, I suspect your whole approach is incorrect, as you seem to be crossreferencing your `@match` array with itself. `$match[$i] =~ $match[$j]` is probably not the right way to compare, as it will perform a regex match between the strings. My first thought was that you wanted `$i == $j` or `$match[$i] eq $match[$j]`.

Comment: Just imagine ... At some point some IoT device cobbled together by this process may land in your security monitoring system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `/` unquoted inside a `s///` construct. Instead of backslashes, you can use different delimiters:

```
s#UART90_BASE_ADDRESS#$defines_2{ $_ = grep{/$match[$i]/} (keys %defines_2)}#;
```

It fixes the syntax error, but I fear it still won't do what you want. Without data, it's hard to test, though.

Comment: thanx It was giving two errors but  now its still giving 1 syntax error in the same line where I'v used #  as you suggested ! It is saying syntax error near = but i am  not able to figure out where !

Comment: @Grace90: Weird. I'm getting no errors. Did you copy&paste or edit?

Comment: I copied and pasted the line suggested by you and then it removed one error and now its saying "syntax error near =" . Sometimes it gives error in the wrong line . Probably its = in this line "my @lin = <$out_pointer>;" but i cant figure out what error!

Comment: okay got it i had not put "$_ =~"  before the line  you suggested ..my bad ..thankyou so much!..now its giving no errors though i yet have to figure out if it works :)

Comment: @Grace90: `$_ =~` is optional. If there is no variable to bind a match/substitution against, `$_` is the default.

Comment: yes thats what i also was wondering but i just made two changes in my code ,first  put "$_ =~" and second below this code i had a code chunk that i had put between "=pod" and "=cut" i removed that and it started running fine

Comment: @Grace90: All POD directives must be surrounded by empty lines.

Comment: ohh ok i just read it at "http://perldoc.perl.org/perlpod.html#Command-Paragraph" after seeing your comment ...got it thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

What I think you're doing is editing a number of text files whose names look like `file_no_1.txt` etc. You're doing that by copying the current file to `t_code.txt` and then reading that file line by line, editing as required, as writing the lines back to the original text file.

The problem with that approach is that the file will be copied and rewritten many times, and it would be better to read the whole file into an array, make all the edits, and then write them back in one operation. That would be fine unless the file is enormous — say, several GB.

Here's some code that implements that approach. You see that `$file_name` is defined and `@lines` is filled *outside* the inner loop. The innermost loop modifies the elements of `@lines` and, outside that loop again, `@lines` is written back to the original text file.

I couldn't fathom a couple of things about your code.

- I'm not sure if you should be using `=~` or if you intended a simple `eq`. The former does a *contains* test, and you had a problem in the past where you meant to check that the first string had the second *at the end*
- The `grep` call

  ```
  grep{/$match[$i]/} (keys %defines_2)
  ```

  worries me, as it can potentially return more than one key of the `%defines_2` hash, in which case your own code will insert what is pretty much a random selection from the hash elements

If your code is working then that's fine, but if not then I hope this helps you fix it. If you need more help on this chunk of code then you should include a small sample of the data so that we can better understand what is going on.

```
for my $i (0 .. $#match) {

  my $file_name = "file_no_$i.txt";

  my @lines = do {
    open my $in_fh, '<', 't_code.txt' or die $!;
    <$in_fh>;
  };

  for my $j (0 .. $#match) {

    next if $match[$i] =~ $match[$j];

    for ( @lines ) {
      my ($match) = grep { /$match[$i]/ } keys %defines_2;
      s/UART90_BASE_ADDRESS/$defines_2{$match}/;
    }
  }

  open my $out_fh, '>', $file_name or die qq{Can't open "$file_name" for output: $!};
  print $out_fh $_ for @lines;
  close $out_fh or die qq{Failed to close output file "$file_name": $!};
}
```